# Adding a layout update handle in the category backend "XML Layout update" does not work

Tags: magento2

I have created the file

```
frontend/layout/foo_example.xml
```

in a custom module.

Now I want to "call" this update in the category backend

[image]

This does not have any effect.

If I create the file `catalog_category_view_id_15.xml` in the same module with the contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="foo_example" />
</page>
```

it works fine.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only some xml tag for this feature such as `referenceContainer` or `referenceBlock` in body DOM. Layout Update not support `update` handle tag

Example: You want add custom block or static image in category page

In field Layout Update XML

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
            name="block_test" 
            as="block_custom" 
            template="Vendor_ModuleName::block_template_file_name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: But it validates...entering something wrong on the category backend causes an error...  But still you might be right